# Dev Desktop SSL connection error

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, drupal, acquia

I am currently using Dev Desktop as my local development environment.
Everything as working perfectly until I inputted the ssl code snippet into my ht access file which is needed to make the site https.

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301

]
```

Now when I try to open my local site I recieve the following error:

```
SSL connection error
Hide details
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? thank you.

Kind Regards,
Aisling

Comment: First guess is that you have no or no valid SSL certificate in place, but your question is quite vague.

Comment: Hi Alexander, The ssl cert is in place and working live. However now I want to make some changes locally and I am receiving the ssl error. On Acquia Forums the issue seems to be unresolved https://forums.acquia.com/acquia-products-and-services/dev-desktop/errsslprotocolerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe SSL is supported in Dev Desktop.

I think your options are:

- Remove the SSL redirect and continue to work locally without it
- Use a different dev environment (like XAMPP) and config the SSL there
- Acquia offers free dev sandboxes for drupal - I *think* SSL is supported. If so, you could migrate and test there https://www.acquia.com/free